# Encountering Error in Angularjs : [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got this piece of code where a directive is inside a directive:

```
<script>

app.directive('testChart', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                controllerAs: 'chartCtrl',
                template: '<div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
                controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$compile', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {
                    $scope.chartId = $scope.$id;
                    let content = angular.element('<div><div id="container'+ $scope.chartId + '"></div></div>');
                    $element.append(content);
                    $compile($element.contents())($scope); //<---- recompilation 
                    var html = $element.html();
                    var hc = Highcharts.chart('container' + $scope.chartId, {

                    });
                }]
            };
        })      
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIKIWZCHGPPD

When adding template: `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` to the template I get the error: `Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found.`

What's the cause of this error? I've looked through the other questions with the same problem but I am unable to apply those solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recompilation line in `testChart` directive causing problem. Before execution of that line angular already created (& compiled) testChart directive as:

```
<div ng-transclude=""></div>
```

Later on appending some element & compiling it treats it as a simple div element having ng-transclude directive, which by default showing `Orphan ngTransclude Directive` error. So, just remove that line from directive definition, and everything else is working fine. So your directive definition will be (same excluding recompilation line)

```
app.directive('testChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controllerAs: 'chartCtrl',
    template: '<div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$compile', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {

      $scope.chartId = $scope.$id;
      let content = angular.element('<div><div id="container' + $scope.chartId + '"></div></div>');
      $element.append(content);
      //$compile($element.contents())($scope); //<---- recompilation 
      var html = $element.html();
      console.log(html);
      var hc = Highcharts.chart('container' + $scope.chartId, {

      });
    }]
  }; 
})
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aRR2gEuVWyKhddyE3bOn?p=preview)

In some cases where you'll need compulsory compilation, do it before appending it to directive template here ng-transclude is used.